# Rudin Principles of Mathematics analysis 3.3(b)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I want to check if my proof of the following "obvious" facts are correct

Suppose $\{s_{n}\}$ and $\{t_{n}\}$ are complex sequences and $\lim_{n \to \infty}s_{n} = s$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} t_{n} = t$. Then

$\lim_{n \to \infty}cs_{n} = cs$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}(c+s_{n}) = c + s$ for any real number $c$

Proof attempt:

(1): Given $\epsilon > \frac{1}{|c|}$. There exists integers $N_{1}$ such that for $n \geq N_{1}$, $|c(s_{n}-s)| = |c||s_{n}-s| < \epsilon.$

(2): Given $ \epsilon > 0$. There exists integers $N_{2}$ such that for $n \geq N_{2}$, $|c + (s_{n} - s)| \leq |c| + |(s_{n} - s)|$. Then since we know $s_{n} \rightarrow s$ this is less than $\epsilon + |c|$ which is less than some multiple of $\epsilon$

I think the ending of the proof of property 2 can be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement,
$$|c + (s_{n} - s)| \leq |c| + |(s_{n} - s)|$$
should have been
$$|(c + s_{n}) -(c+s))|=|s_n-s| <\epsilon $$

Comment: Thanks, makes sense!

Comment: Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1):

Generally, we do not set conditions for $\epsilon$; instead, we choose the appropriate $N$. So for the 2 limits above, the proof will look as follows:

Since $s_n \to s$ as $n\to\infty$, for any given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N_1, N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
n \ge N_1 \,\Rightarrow\, |s_n - s| < \epsilon
$$
and
$$
n \ge N_2 \,\Rightarrow\, |s_n - s| < \frac{\epsilon}{|c|}
$$

Then choose $N = N_1$.
$$
n \ge N \,\Rightarrow\, |(c+s_n) - (c+s)| = |s_n - s| < \epsilon
$$
Thus, $\lim_{n\to\infty}c+s_n = c+s$.

Similarly, choose $N = N_2$.
$$
n \ge N \,\Rightarrow\, |cs_n - cs| = |c||s_n-s| < \epsilon
$$
Thus, $\lim_{n\to\infty}cs_n = cs$.